# Switch statement with closed-ranges covering full Float range

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, range

I am expecting the code below to cover the full `Float` range of which I use only a very small part just above 0.

My app however sometimes crashes in the field because it hits `default: fatalError()`.

What could possibly be wrong here?

```
var value: Float // Between a little above 0 and about 15.

...

switch value
{
case ...3: return 0
case 3...10: return 1
case 10...: return 2
default: fatalError()
}
```

Comment: My guess would be it's only matching for whole numbers. Try it with a whole number.

Comment: Print the value of your float. It’s probably nan, or infinity.

Comment: Infinity is covered by the last range. NaN cannot be covered by a range. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This switch will fall all the way through default for example if value is `Float.nan` or `Float.signalingNaN`, so it's technically possible for the app to legitimately crash at that point.

Consider adding some logging before crashing to check which value causes it to crash.

Comment: This was the cause. I've avoided this issue with a `guard` testing `value.isNaN` somewhere upwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have covered all cases except for the values whose eight exponent bits are all 1s. None of these are "Between a little above 0 and about 15", so your assumption is currently incorrect.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding